# write from kafka to hdfs (with cloudera cdk?)

Tags: hdfs, cloudera, apache-kafka

I would like to design a system that has an application browser which sends messages to Kafka. Consumers should write events to HDFS in avro format.

How should this look like?

When exactly is a good time to ack the message?

How exactly can I append to hdfs file? I read about cdk and it looks like something in the good direction. What I can't is how/when to flush the records.

Does anyone have a good example?

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using  nathanmarz's [storm](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm) along with Kafka. Kafka has a nice integration support named `Kafka Spout` that pull data from the Kafka queue (topic) and feed into storm topology. You can then easily perform almost anything using the storm `bolt`, even writing to HDFS.

For a sample you can go through these following project for a quick look, hope this will give you some heads up

[Kafka-hadoop loader](https://github.com/michal-harish/kafka-hadoop-loader) 
[kafka-hadoop consumer](https://github.com/kafka-dev/kafka/tree/master/contrib/hadoop-consumer)

Also take a look into [this article](http://oobaloo.co.uk/tag/hdfs) talking about Kafka interacting with HDFS

Comment: But doesn't it mean I have to start map/reduce job that fetch the data from kaka and push it to HDFS?

Comment: I would prefer something simpler that will allow me to add each record I get directly and immediately to HDFS without the need to start scheduled map/reduce

Comment: you can always write your own logic to write into HDFS .. just need to implement that inside the bolt's nextTuple() method .. does this make sense ?

Comment: It does, what I am missing is exactly this logic. How can I write a new avro record to HDFS and c"commit" it so it will be available even if the writing process died a split second afterwards